# File.(filename).mtime the same output format like Date.today (ruby)

Tags: ruby

I want to subtract the result of **File.mtime** and **Date.today**. **Time** and **weekends** are ignored. I am after something like

**Date.today** - **File.mtime**

File.mtime gives me `Fri Oct 08 11:00:18 +1100 2010`
and 
Date.today `2010-10-11`

I thought that [to_s()](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Date.html#M000685) would work for me but `File.mtime(filename).to_s` gives me the same result like `File.mtime(filename)`

any idea how I can get the desired date format from File.mtime? And why to_s is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
irb(main):001:0> File.mtime("file")
=> 2010-10-08 17:56:10 +0800
irb(main):002:0> File.mtime("file").year
=> 2010
irb(main):003:0> File.mtime("file").month
=> 10
irb(main):004:0> File.mtime("file").day
=> 8
```

Similarly with Date

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'date'         
=> true                                 
irb(main):002:0> Date.today         
=> #<Date: 2010-10-11 (4910961/2,0,2299161)>
irb(main):003:0> Date.today.year            
=> 2010                                     
irb(main):004:0> Date.today.month
=> 10                            
irb(main):005:0> Date.today.day
=> 11
```

Or you can use `strftime`

```
irb(main):001:0> File.mtime("file").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
=> "2010-10-08"
```

Comment: yes, something like that. Do I have to use .year .month and .day for File.mtime or is there any way how I can use one command/methond

Comment: yes, it works. One more and last question. Any easier way how to write `puts ( (Date.strptime(File.mtime("file").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))..(Date.today)).select {|d| (1..5).include?(d.wday) }.size - 1` it does what I want but it seems to me written too complicated

Comment: And how does that exactly answer OP's question about how to make the math operations work between Date.today and File.mtime (whatever their visual output is set to)?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Time.now` and convert to days manually:

```
age = Time.now - File.mtime(filename)
age_in_days = (age / 24*60*60).to_i
```

Comment: not sure if I would be able to use .wday I am only after week days

Comment: @Radek: Fair enough, though that was hard to guess from the way you posed your question.

Comment: you're right. It wasn't in my original question. I updated it.